# How to get a value from MySQL n days before from CURDATE()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join 4 tables to list all the values from a table those have the duration from last updated to current date is more that the duration in other table, table are given below (my English not good to understand so am explaining with examble)

first table `daily_tasks`

```
+---------+---------+
| task_id | type_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Second Table `daily_task_report`

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| report_id | task_id | task_date  |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|         1 |       1 | 2015-09-10 |
|         2 |       3 | 2015-09-10 |
|         3 |       1 | 2015-09-11 |
|         4 |       3 | 2015-09-16 |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Third Table `duration_types`

```
+---------+---------------+------------------------+
| type_id | duration_type | duration_time(in days) |
+---------+---------------+------------------------+
|       1 | Daily Task    |                      1 |
|       2 | Weekly Task   |                      6 |
|       3 | Monthly Task  |                     26 |
|       4 | Yearly Task   |                    313 |
+---------+---------------+------------------------+
```

Fourth Table `calendar`

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| cal_id |  cal_date  | holiday |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      1 | 2015-09-10 |       0 |
|      2 | 2015-09-11 |       0 |
|      3 | 2015-09-12 |       0 |
|      4 | 2015-09-13 |       1 |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

Here `daily_tasks.type_id` is from `duration_types.type_id` and `daily_task_report.task_id` is from `daily_tasks.task_id`. I want to select all the `task_id` those `task_date` and `current_date` difference will greater than `duration_time`, also while calculating the duration i have to avoid the dates those have `holiday=1` from `calendar`.
I tried queries but not proper, i got the values without including the `calendar` table, but that not a good way, query is taking more time to execute.

```
"SELECT dailyTasks.task_id FROM 
                          (SELECT tab.* FROM (SELECT 
                          tasks.task_type,report.*
                          FROM daily_tasks AS tasks
                          LEFT JOIN daily_task_reports AS report ON tasks.task_id=report.task_id
                          WHERE 1 ORDER BY report.task_date DESC) as tab GROUP BY tab.d_task_id) AS dailyTasks
                          LEFT JOIN duration_types AS type ON dailyTasks.task_type=type.type_id
                          WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dailyTasks.task_date)>=type.duration_time"
```

Please someone help, I stuck in this section

Answer (score 0):

According to given table You have some unexpected text or unknown columns in your query

> Try this query

```
"SELECT dailyTasks.d_task_id FROM 
                      (SELECT tab.* FROM 
                                (SELECT tasks.type_id,report.* FROM daily_tasks AS tasks

                                    LEFT JOIN daily_task_reports AS report ON tasks.task_id=report.task_id

                                    ORDER BY report.task_date DESC) 

                                as tab GROUP BY tab.task_id) AS dailyTasks

                                LEFT JOIN duration_types AS type ON dailyTasks.type_id=type.type_id

                      WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dailyTasks.task_date)>=type.duration_time"
```

> It can be also works in single query

```
SELECT tasks.task_id FROM daily_tasks AS tasks

        LEFT JOIN daily_task_reports AS report ON tasks.task_id=report.task_id
        LEFT JOIN duration_types AS type ON tasks.type_id = type.type_id and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),report.task_date) >=  type.duration_time
```

*I tried but not exclude that id which have holiday in calendar 
You can create it on your coding side I gave you new query included with calendar 
*

```
SELECT tasks.task_id,report.task_date,calendar.holiday FROM daily_tasks AS tasks

        LEFT JOIN daily_task_reports AS report ON tasks.task_id=report.task_id
        LEFT JOIN duration_types AS type ON tasks.type_id = type.type_id and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),report.task_date) >=  type.duration_time
        LEFT JOIN calendar ON report.task_date=calendar.cal_date 
        where calendar.holiday = '0'
        order By report.task_date desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the way i want, I think it is taking more execution time because of three select query, also I want to include the calendar, to exclude the holiday

Comment: @BasilPJoy update my answer your given query can also work with single select statement

Comment: This will work and it will list all the tasks, I want only the last updated tasks, also i have to exclude the dates in calendar those have holiday, Ajeeth, I gave my query just for to explain what I'm trying to do,

Comment: there is fourth table calendar which is not have any relation with other three tables, please explain how to join them with calendar table.
And i have updated query "SELECT tasks.task_id" from "SELECT tasks.*,report.*,type.* "

If you want last updated task_date of task_id only than

Comment: If you want last updated task_date of task_id only than
"SELECT tasks.task_id,report.task_date " and at last "rder by report.task_date desc " you Got first row id last updated task_id

Comment: Calendar is listing full year calendar of a company, including holidays and working days, tasks are giving to an employee with daily, weekly and monthly, i want to find the expiring date of the task, but while counting the days we can include only working days, not holidays, for that i want to use calendar. please give any suggestion if you have.

Comment: @BasilPJoy I have added new query with join calander

Comment: Not getting the correct answer, in this example third task (tasks.task_id 3) is weekly task and its last updated date is 2015-09-16. again this task should listed only after 2015-09-22 and if in calendar any date between these two date is holiday then it should list on 2015-09-23. currently in your query task 3 also listing. it should list only task 1&2 not 3. I think you understand my point.

Comment: for excluding holiday date try with "  where calendar.holiday = 0 " before order by,  
I think in holiday column 0,1 is true or false?, 
i updated in last query ...... i think its working @BasilPJoy

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I want. I will tell you the requirement. Every day one file will execute automatically for adding today's task. weekly tasks are repeating only after 6 days from the last updated date, if one day is off for the company system wont consider it as a working day, it will count only working days. daily tasks are like it will added every working day to today's task. if yesterday one weekly task is updated then it will list only after 6 working days.

Comment: @BasilPJoy This kind of problem without doing practical, we can't solve. so sorry about that "Good Luck".